# Spark - How many executors for application master in Yarn client mode

Tags: apache-spark

## Question

In Yarn client mode, how many executors are required for the application master (AM)?

In Yarn **cluster** mode, according to [How-to: Tune Your Apache Spark Jobs (Part 2)](https://blog.cloudera.com/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/), the AM requires 2 executors.

> A better option would be to use --num-executors **17** --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 19G. **Why?**
>   This config results in three executors on all nodes except for the one with the AM, which will have two executors.

## Update

I misunderstood the article. AM is a JVM, so if running 3 JVM (executor) per node, then AM node can run 2 executors. YARN mode has nothing to do with how many non-executor JVM required for AM process. Always 1 JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Guess is that your execution mode (cluster / client) has nothing to do with the AM in terms of impact. Yarn Application Master always runs on the cluster and is decorrelated from the driver/client (which is the only one impacted by your exec mode)

**1 -** As you can see below Client and App Master are decorelated

[image]

**2 -** Spark Cluster mode : Driver is executer on a driver node

[image]

**3 -** Spark Client Mode : Driver is executed from the worker/machine where the spark job submission originated from

[image]